# how to get option value when user input

Tags: angular

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array; let i=index; let j=item;">
<td>
<select (change)="getStatus($event.target.value)">
    <option value="1">Value</option>
    <option value="2">%Change</option>
</select>

<input #box1 (click)="update(box1.value,2,item)" (click) = "box1.value = ''"/>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

TS:

```
status: string = '';
getStatus(deviceValue){

this.status = deviceValue.valueOf(); 
return this.status;

}

update(value: string, index: number, item: number) {

if(this.status=='1'){ 

something

}else{

other thing

}
```

How can i get the option values after user input ?

Now the "statue" can be check once only, if user change one option, the status of the other drop down box  will also change too and that's not i want

Comment: what do you want actually?

Comment: Your code is not clear. You have added two click event handlers to single input

Comment: after user input , the option values will be check , if ==1 do something, else do other thing

Comment: how can i pass "box1.value" into TS so that i can clear input box after user input